# Decide the dimension of maximal ideals

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

Let $A=\mathbb C[x,y]/(y^2-x^3,y^5-x^3)$. I want to know the dimension of each maximal ideal over $\mathbb C$. Actually I can't decide it's maximal ideal. And how to decide its dimension?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To find the maximal ideals, use the Nullstellensatz.  If $I$ is an ideal in a polynomial ring over an algebraically closed field, then each point of the common zeros of $I$, $\mathcal Z(I)$, is in bijective correspondence with the maximal ideals containing $I$ (equivalently, maximal ideals in the quotient by $I$).

Comment: I know,but in this way how to decide the dimension of its local ring over $\mathbb C$?

Comment: Is that means that for example $(0,0)$ is in $Z(I)$ so A has a  maximal ideal $\mathbb C[x,y]/(x,y)$?

Comment: It means that $(x,y)$ is a maximial ideal of $\Bbb C[x,y]$ containing $(y^2-x^3,y^5-x^3)$.  The maximial ideal of the quotient is just the image by the quotient.  So $(x,y)/(y^2-x^3,y^5-x^3)$ is the maximal ideal of the quotient ring corresponding to the point $(0,0)$.  I do not remember how to compute the requested dimension right now, so I only attempted an answer to the "I can't decide it's maximal ideal" part.